# How to show that a collection of stationary points are not local min/max?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> **Question:** Let $f:\Bbb{R^2}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be given by $f(x,y)=e^{y+x\sin(x)}$. Show that $f$ has infinitely man stationary
>   points with none of them being local minimums (or maximums) of the
>   function.

**Answer:**

By considering the fact we must have $\nabla f=0$ we can conclude using that $e^{y+x\sin(y)}\neq0$ we need $\sin(y)=0=(1+x\cos(y))$ from here it is easy to spot that there will be infinitely many stationary points of the form:$$ 
(1,n\pi)~~\text{n even} \\(-1,n\pi)~ \text{n odd}$$

okay so now I don't know how to proceed, how do I show that none of these can be local min (or max)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that finding maximum and minimum points of $f(x,y)=e^{y+x\sin y}$ is the same as finding maximum and minimum points of $g(x,y)=y+x\sin y$. As you pointed out, the critical points have the form $\{(1,(2k)\pi),(-1,(2k+1)\pi): k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

The Hessian matrix is given by $$H=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial^2g}{\partial x^2} & \dfrac{\partial^2g}{\partial x\partial y}\\ \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y \partial x} & \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \cos y\\ \cos y & -x\sin y\end{bmatrix}$$ and we have:

$$H(1,2k\pi)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \hspace{1cm} 
H(1,(2k+1)\pi)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ which can be determined to be saddle points by the second derivative test (both determinants are negative)